# Accessing any object created in another class

Tags: java, class, object

I´m fairly new to programming and I´ve been stuck on this for a while now so any help to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

I´m working on the infamous bank account program and having trouble with accessing a particular object from a different class. I have two classes, Customer and Banklogic. The Customer class obviously creates customer objects with a social security number (pnr) and a name. The Banklogic class handles and manipulates these objects with different methods such as adding them to the bank or changing their name.

My problem is that when I´ve created say three customer objects the only one I can access is the last one created. I need to be able to access any object in order to invoke methods on them.

This is the constructor of the Customer class:

`public Customer(long pNr, String name)
    {
        this.pNr = pNr;
        this.name = name;
    }`

This is the method to add a new customer to the bank in the BankLogic class (with a few differnt lists):

```
public boolean addCustomer(String name, long pNr)
{
    if(!pNrList.contains(pNr))                                  
    {
        customer = new Customer(pNr, name);
        customerList.add(customer);
        String client = Long.toString(customer.getpNr()) + "     " + customer.getName();
        kunder.add(client);
        pNrList.add(pNr);
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

If I create three objects in a tester class or in the BankLogic class like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    BankLogic a = new BankLogic();
    a.addCustomer("JEAN", 66);
    a.addCustomer("JEN", 67);
    a.addCustomer("ANNA", 70);
}
```

When I try to access one of them with a getter method from the Customer class, the only returned object is the last one created, in this case:

> Anna 70

I don´t think there´s a problem with the getter method from Customer class:

```
public long getpNr() 
{
    return pNr;
}
```

I´ve tried another getter mehod as well which won´t work either:

```
public long getpNr(long pNr) 
{       
    if(this.pNr == pNr)
    {
        return pNr;
    }
    else return -1;
}
```

The customerList in the BankLogic class is an Arraylist that holds Customer objects but I can´t figure out how to access the different objects from this either (if it is possible that is).

PS
This is my first post here so please forgive any errors or if this has already been answered elsewhere..
Thanks / Johan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating only single object of class `BankLogic` and only updating the attributes(name and pnr) of same object by calling the method `addCustomer`.Update code as below to create 3 different objects :

```
BankLogic a = new BankLogic();
    a.addCustomer("JEAN", 66);
BankLogic b = new BankLogic();
    b.addCustomer("JEN", 67);
BankLogic c = new BankLogic();
    c.addCustomer("ANNA", 70);
```

Editing :
Use below code then the size of the list will be 3 and correct name/pnr will be reflected

```
    ArrayList<BankLogic> obj = new ArrayList<BankLogic>();
        BankLogic a = new BankLogic();
        a.addCustomer("JEAN", 66);
        obj.add(a);
        a = new BankLogic();
        a.addCustomer("JEN", 67);
        obj.add(a);
        a = new BankLogic();
        a.addCustomer("ANNA", 70);
        obj.add(a);
```

Comment: This was the way I originally had done it, the thing is that there really should only be one BankLogic object = 1 bank, with lots of different customers. If i check the length of the ArrayList<Customer> customerList after three calls the value is 3, does this mean 3 objects have been created but their attributes are all the same (the last added)?

Comment: @Slim After every addition of the object in the ArryList you need to create new object.You can reuse the reference like BankLogic a = new BankLogic();
    a.addCustomer("JEAN", 66);
a = new BankLogic();
    a.addCustomer("JEN", 67);
a = new BankLogic();
    a.addCustomer("ANNA", 70);

Comment: When I do that I still only get the last object added and now the size of the list is only 1 which must mean that when creating a new object it overwrites the last one? Should the ArrayList be static or non-static btw?

Comment: @Slim updated answer, it will return size as 3 and correct value will be reflected.

Comment: Yes it does! But this means that there are three BankLogic Objects created right? And this list has to be a static one as well?

Comment: Yes you cant save multiple value of attribute in single object.You can  use non-static list.Just see above answer @Slim